# Sending an Image as an Argument for a Flutter Platform Channel Method

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development, flutter-platform-channel

I am building a Flutter Application, and for one of the API's I am using, it does not have Flutter support, only Android and iOS.  My solution to this was to use Platform Channels, but how would I pass an Image as an argument?

To explain a little further, I am picking an image from the gallery with `ImagePicker().getImage` in the dart file, and I want to send the image selected to the method in the Kotlin file that will do something with the image on its end and return a string.

After looking at the docs, I was able to make a channel like this:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('app.dev/channel'); 
final string result = await platform.invokeMethod('returnStringfromImage');
```

And in the Kotlin file:

```
 private val CHANNEL = "app.dev/channel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            call, result ->
            if (call.method == "returnStringfromImage") {
                val return = returnStringfromImage(call.arguments)
                
            }

            else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }

    }
```

How would I send the image over, and pass it as an argument for the returnStringfromImage() method?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the picked image to any of these [supported types](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#codec), most probably as bytes (`Uint8list`) to send over to the platform side.

ImagePicker would return a `File`, so You can call `readAsBytes` on it to get `Uint8list`. Then you can pass it via arguments of `invokeMethod`.